# Python long array of IP subnets (works, but slow)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long array (+/- 1000 entries, 8 million IPs) of IP subnets, and I want to check if (a list of) certain IPs are in that array.
The code that I have for it, works. But is quite "slow". Since I have to lookup more than one IP address, I want to make the search faster. Are there any ways to improve the search trough the array?

Example array:

```
nets = [
    '192.168.1.0/24',
    '192.168.2.0/24',
    '192.168.3.0/24',
]
```

The code to search:

```
def search(ip_address):
    for net in nets:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(ip_address) in ipaddress.ip_network(net):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: An obvious optimisation would be to pre-compute the ``ipaddress.ip_network``s instead of re-computing them on each search. Have you tried that?

Comment: As usual, a profiler would likely show a lot of the time here is likely spent in the `ip_network` and `ip_address` constructors. :)

Comment: Doing `cached_get_net = cache(ipaddress.ip_network)` and using that instead of `ipaddress.ip_network()` directly makes this 2-3 times faster for a list of 5000 random IPs with nearly zero effort. Doing the same for `ip_address` yields a speedup of 18x over the original; using a limited lru_cache about 9x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to express the networks as a list of integer `range`s.

```
from ipaddress import ip_address, ip_network

nets = [
    '192.168.1.0/24',
    '192.168.2.0/24',
    '192.168.3.0/24',
]

ip_ranges = [
    (range(int(n.network_address), int(n.broadcast_address)), n)
    for n in map(ip_network, nets)
]

ip = int(ip_address('192.168.2.10'))

results = [n for r, n in ip_ranges if ip in r]
print(results)
```

I did not measure it, but it seemed to be quite snappy with 30,000 networks. (I only did `nets * 10000` to beef up the number, and `print(len(results))` came up with `10000` pretty much instantly.)

Comment: I would expect the ``ip_network`` to already use such an optimised containment check, and assume the OP's code is slow because they recreate the networks on each search. Did you compare your approach of pre-computed ranges vs. working with pre-computed networks?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, I didn't, the OP is very welcome to do so. :) My suspicion was the same (recreating the Network and IP instances for every check is slow),  but  the `__contains__()` check of Python's `_BaseNetwork` class does a couple more things that are not really necessary here ([see source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5081e78efde901556398615eb477c63c836686e5/Lib/ipaddress.py#L742)), and I think `range()` can do it faster.

Comment: Range does seem to do it faster, but the time for a benchmark with a list of random IPs is still dominated by `int(ip_address(...))` (since caching that makes things fast).

Comment: @AKX True, but I can't think of a good way to do it faster, since the string IP must be normalized into something usable no matter how you go about it with the network membership check.

Comment: Thank you. This loads almost instant, instead of the previous 30 seconds.
@MisterMiyagi recreating the IP address indeed slowed it up. But when creating it once, it 'only' halved the time (to 15 seconds).